# Hazelcast - Persist data when shutting down the last node

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I'm currently researching Hazelcast to use as a message queue and shared in-memory storage in a cluster.

I was wondering how to handle the situation when the last node goes down. I'd want to persist all hazelcast-managed data, queues, etc to disk with the ability to startup again at a later time.

The MapStore and MapLoad feature looks interesting, but when is this used? The documentation says it is used whenever needed, but I would only need it when shutting down the last node. There is no need to keep all data persisted during normal operation.

Also the writing to disk should happen at the very end, so no new data gets added in the meantime.

Does anyone have experience or advice on how to handle this type of situation for a newbie?

PS: I'm also using Spring and Mongo, btw.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we don't have functionality like this available out of the box.

You might want to have a look at the QueueStore/QueueLoader interface. It provides the same functionality for the Queue as the MapStore/MapLoader for the map.

We are working on a disk based storage solution for all data-structures, but that isn't ready yet.

Comment: Is it available now?